# How to configure addition library folders for Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have legacy, non Visual Studio project. Its structure is:

```
-root_folder
-root_folder/folder1
-root_folder/folder1/main.cpp
-root_folder/folder1/fun.cpp
-root_folder/folder2
-root_folder/folder2/bar.cpp
-root_folder/folder2/foo.h
.... many different folders
```

I work with project under folder1.

**root_folder/folder1/main.cpp:**

```
#include <folder2/foo.h>
....
```

I have the error: `Error can not open source file "folder2/foo.h>"`.

Of course, I added the folder `root_folder` in `Project -> properties -> c/c++ section -> additional include directories.`

I cannot change this source code, so I need right configure project settings.

Also, I have one more problem. Visual studio does not show my folders structure. It just show folder `Source Files`, which contains all thousands files.

Comment: you need to use `project properties -> vc++ directories -> include directories`; add the path you need there

Comment: @twentylemon, I added root folder in this place, The error still exists.

Comment: Try using `#include "folder2/foo.h"` instead of `#include <folder2/foo.h>`

Comment: About the folder structure, select the project in the Solution Explorer and press "Show all files" on the bar on top.

Comment: @Banex, it works, but I cannot change this code.

Comment: @Banex, About the folder structure, it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio looks in "VC++ Directories" -> "Include Directories" for the include files specified in angle brackets.
You need to add you path there:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.ToolsOptionsPages.Projects.VCDirectories%29&rd=true

P.S. Just noticed that this answer was given earlier, and rejected.
However, it most certainly works; tested with VS2013.